# how can I read and add objects from a file by skipping the first 3 lines?

Tags: java, object, arraylist, java.util.scanner, string-formatting

I am basically working on a small piece of code that is apart of a bigger project. I am dealing with reading objects from a file and storing it in an ArrayList. I am getting a java.util.InputMismatchException even though I am 99.9% sure that my variables are accordingly. Meaning that I am not calling read.next() for an integer.

However, I think that even though the variables are correct, I am still getting the InputMismatchException error.

I spaced the data for each object in the file using String formatting, does that interfere with the reading of the file? Would that cause a InputMismatchException?

File I am reading and storing from:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Firstname      Lastname       Goals               Caps                Assists             
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Jack           John           6                   23                  12                   
Donald         Evans          2                   3                   2                   
Momcilo        Stevens        12                  34                  1                   
Aleksandra     Freece         0                   3                   1                   
Mark           Hemming        0                   0                   0
```

Code that is supposed to skip the first 3 lines and store the objects:

```
        ArrayList<Player> x = new ArrayList<Player>();
        System.out.println("Enter the name of the file that you wish to delete information from: ");
        String name = scan.next();
        try{
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(name));
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(br);
            br.readLine();
            br.readLine();
            br.readLine();
            while (scan.hasNext()) {
                x.add(new Player(scan.next(),scan.next(),scan.nextInt(),scan.nextInt(),scan.nextInt()));
            }
        }
        catch (IOException ex) {
               System.out.println("Unable to open file." + ex.toString());
            }
```

Error that I am getting:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
    at roster.Team.delete(Team.java:93)
    at roster.Driver.main(Driver.java:34)
```

Comment: Is the code you're showing from the `delete` method in the `Team` class?

Answer (score 0):

The code worked perfectly fine for me. Also, make sure to wrap your Closeable resources in a try-with-resources or at least close them. I'm referring to BufferedReader and Scanner. They both implement Closeable and need to be closed to release the resources they lock.

Code:

```java
@StackOverFlowAnswer(url = "")
public class ReadBySkip {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in)) {
            ArrayList<Player> x = new ArrayList<>();

            System.out.println("Enter the name of the file that you wish to delete information from: ");

            String name = scanner.next();

            try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(name));
                 Scanner scan = new Scanner(br)) {
                br.readLine();
                br.readLine();
                br.readLine();
                while (scan.hasNext()) {
                    x.add(new Player(scan.next(), scan.next(), scan.nextInt(), scan.nextInt(), scan.nextInt()));
                }
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                System.out.println("Unable to open file." + ex.toString());
            }
            System.out.println("x: " + x);
        }
    }

    private static class Player {

        private final String firstName;

        private final String lastName;

        private final int goals;

        private final int caps;

        private final int assists;

        private Player(String firstName, String lastName, int goals, int caps, int assists) {
            this.firstName = firstName;
            this.lastName = lastName;
            this.goals = goals;
            this.caps = caps;
            this.assists = assists;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Player{" +
                    "firstName='" + firstName + '\'' +
                    ", lastName='" + lastName + '\'' +
                    ", goals=" + goals +
                    ", caps=" + caps +
                    ", assists=" + assists +
                    '}' + "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Enter the name of the file that you wish to delete information from: 
readbyskip.txt
x: [Player{firstName='Jack', lastName='John', goals=6, caps=23, assists=12}
, Player{firstName='Donald', lastName='Evans', goals=2, caps=3, assists=2}
, Player{firstName='Momcilo', lastName='Stevens', goals=12, caps=34, assists=1}
, Player{firstName='Aleksandra', lastName='Freece', goals=0, caps=3, assists=1}
, Player{firstName='Mark', lastName='Hemming', goals=0, caps=0, assists=0}
]
```

Comment: I closed all of the resources, but nothing was fixed. May I send you my entire project so you can see what the issue is? Thanks.

Comment: One thing you can do is debug. On each line, print out the Player object. Then see which line it is failing at. Then look at that line and compare it to others to see what the difference is.

Comment: It does not print any player objects because nothing is added. It doesn't let me add in the first place.

Comment: The first thing that I would check is that there is a file that has the given input. If it does not exist, create it. When the application asks for a file name, provide that file name and the relative path.

Comment: My file exists. I have been able to delete from a file but because I have to skip lines this time, it becomes more complicated.